# Position setting in XML or Database

Tags: mysql, xml, database, web-applications, drawing

I am trying to figure out what the best approach to store images and texts position in the database or XML file (simple and easy to maintain as possible)?

For example, in the canvas user can choose a image file and the position on the canvas.

If I use XML file there will be some defined tags name, something like this:

```
<template name="Template Name">
  <canvas background="background.jpg">
  <ratings>
    <area x="710" y="150" width="430" height="500" margin="20" image="panel.png" >
      <columns>1</columns>
      <rows>8</rows>
    </area>
    <text font="ScoutCond Bold" size="22" case="upper" style="bold" color="#777777" />
  </ratings>
  </canvas>
</template>
```

`<area>` represents the location and size of the area where ratings are displayed.

`<columns>` and  should be easy to understand!